# Write your answers in rational form. Write down a polynomial $f(x)$ which has a root $\sqrt{5}$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

I rewrite $\sqrt{5}$ in form of $\sqrt{4+1}$ which also can be $\sqrt{2^2+1}$. then I used formula $f(x)=f(a) +f'(a)(x-a)$ . I got $9/4 $.
 I think that not this is what exactly they asked as in the second part of the question, they tell that by using Newton's method, with $x_0=2$ to find  an approximation $x_1$ to $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ is used to find a linear approximation at $x=a$. To find a polynomial $f(x)$ with root $\sqrt{5}$, think about what the other root must be. Hint: it will be a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: thank, i got it

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$x=\sqrt{5}\implies x^2=5\implies x^2-5=0$$